# The EntitySet name 'BIKESEntities.BIKEINFO' could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using repository pattern
I am using Asp.net MVC .I have given call to this repository method from Business Layer.

```
public class Repository:IRepository
{
    private BIKESEntities context;

    public Repository(BIKESEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Save<T>(T entity)
    {            
        context.AddObject("BIKEINFO", entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am getting error while at line  `context.AddObject("BIKEINFO", entity);`

Comment: What are the table names that have been generated in your database? This could be a pluralisation of name issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
context.AddObject(entity.GetType().Name, entity);
```

Or alternatively you could use.

```
context.AddObject(typeof(T).Name, entity);
```

This will use the generic type parameter.

Comment: @SagarK it can't be "SAME" error. can you post the error please? you are no longer using "BIKEINFO" so the error can't remain the same.

Comment: @SagarK Can you modify your question to show the code where you are calling this Save method?

Comment: Got the answer, Actually EntitySetName was different in Properties of edmx file.Thanx for your help.